# NHibernate set fetch strategy

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I'm using NHibernate with fluent api and got `MainEntity` mapping like this:

```
mapping.References(c => c.Parent1).Not.Nullable().Fetch.Select();
mapping.HasMany(c => c.Children1).Fetch.Select();
mapping.HasMany(c => c.Children2).Fetch.Select();
```

Then I'm trying to query MainEntity like this:

```
var query = Session.Query<MainEntity>().Where(e => e.ID == id);
query.Fetch(e => e.Parent1).ToFuture();
query.FetchMany(e => e.Children1).ToFuture();
query.FetchMany(e => e.Children2).ThenFetch(c => c.Children21).ToFuture();
var entity = query.ToFuture().FirstOrDefault();
```

And got sql query like this:

```
select * from MainEntity
left outer join Parent1 on MainEntity.Parent1ID = Parent1.ID
where MainEntity.ID = @id;

select * from MainEntity
left outer join Children1 on MainEntity.ID = Children1.MainEntityID 
where MainEntity.ID = @id;

select * from MainEntity
left outer join Children2 on MainEntity.ID = Children2.MainEntityID
left outer join Children21 on Children2.Children21ID = Children21.ID
where MainEntity.ID = @id;

select * from MainEntity
where MainEntity.ID = @id;
```

But I want NHibernate to select MainEntity at first and then select `Parent1` and `Children1`, `Children2` by condition:

```
select *
from Parent1
where ID = @parent1ID;

select *
from Children1
where MainEntityID = @id;
```

`@parent1ID` and `@id` are selected by first query of MainEntities.

Please, help me to configure mapping to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried other LINQ version ? It should look like this:

```
Query<Parent>()
.FetchMany(x=>x.Children1)
.FetchMany(x=>x.Children)
.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id=param1);
```

and change children mapping to

```
mapping.HasMany(c => c.Children1);
mapping.HasMany(c => c.Children2);
```